# What does Action "NONE" do in Mule transactions

Tags: transactions, mule

In the Mule documentation for [transaction management](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Transaction+Management) there is a section which explains the ACTION attribute for ACTION "NONE" it says

> When it receives a message, Mule resolves the transaction, then executes the operation as non-transactional.

What they mean by "resolves the transaction" ? and how is this different from "NOT_SUPPORTED" ?

In which case will I use NONE and in which case will I use NOT_SUPPORTED ?

An example to explain the concepts will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "resolve the transaction", they mean either commit it or roll it back, depending on its current state. This, if the transaction has been marked as candidate for roll back, it will be rolled back during this "resolution" phase. Otherwise it will be committed. If there's not active transaction, this is a no-op.

`NOT_SUPPORTED` differs from `NONE` in the sense that it doesn't affect at all the current state of the active transaction, if any. It won't resolve a current transaction.

Comment: Thanks makes sense now !! This [question](http://goo.gl/r6HoqS) is on similar lines, mind having a look at it please ?

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!